# Google calendar api edit event error not found

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I try edit event:

```
request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
                    'calendarId': calendarId,
                    'eventId': noteCurrentEventId,
                    'resource': resource
                });
```

But got error

```
 "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
```

How can i fix it? 
Strange, that can add event, but cant edit. Thanks.

Comment: try and do a calendar.list to see what calendars you have access to

Comment: It appears it did not find the event in the calendarId you passed into the request. Are you sure they exist and you have access?